# How to suppress deprecation warning in Swift code (1.2)?

Tags: xcode, swift, suppress-warnings

I have this simple Swift property:

```
private var isPortraitOrientation: Bool {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)
}
```

XCode shows me warning `'Interface orientation' was deprecated in iOS version 8.0`. However, suggested replacement `viewWillTransitionToSize` does not work in custom keyboard extension. So I am forced to use deprecated API... Can I at least supress those warnings so I do not see them every time I compile?

Comment: You shouldn't suppress it, the warning can be helpful when migrating to iOS 9... or 10 :) As far as I know, you can suppress deprecation warnings only globally using project settings.

Comment: @Sulthan "You shouldn't suppress it" might acctually be the right answer...

Comment: I have tests that MUST test deprecated stuff and the warning is noise. You should not suppress it is an answer for Quora not for Stack Overflow. Answer the question here, don't debate it.

Answer (score -7):

```
  private var isPortraitOrientation: Bool {
      return UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait
  }
```

Comment: This would create serious bugs. Device orientation is not the same think as  interface orientation. The 2 match most of the time but not all the time - and I need to use interface orientation.

Comment: then use .statusBarOrientation